# GPS and Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-ide, gps, coding-standards

I am working on a project with an Arduino Uno. I want to know if the latitudes and longitudes can be input to the Arduino for the Arduino to move to that particular location. If it's possible then which sensors or actuators are to be used? Please also mention some references for me to read and collect the required information.

Comment: Try this: http://bfy.tw/DbBj

Answer (score 2):

OK, notwithstanding Majenko's excellent suggestion in the comments above, I played around with Arduino and GPS, so I can probably offer a few pointers.

---

**First, GPS**:

All the GPS modules that I have played with give out a series of standard strings of information or "sentences". These sentences are defined by the [National Marine Electronics Association (NMEA) protocol](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm). You are going to want to spend some time learning how to use this information.

The most commonly used string in an NMEA sentence is **$GPRMC**. From this you can extract date, time and position. But there is a lot more useful information in an NMEA sentence, so do your research.

When you have decided which GPS module you want to use, just use Google to search for sample Arduino code specific to that module. That should be enough to get you started.

---

**On the subject of GPS Modules:**

There are many available. Just Google search for "Arduino GPS module".

They vary in price from a few GB pounds to well over a hundred GB pounds. It all depends on what you need from it, and what you can afford. Personally, I got very good results from cheap (~ £5 GB) Neo-6M modules (like the one shown here) with some mobile robots I was experimenting with.

[image: neo-6m]

Now, I've just typed "*Neo-6m GPS Arduino*" into Google, and one of the first sites was this [Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Communicate-Neo-6M-GPS-to-Arduino/), which has more than enough information to get you going with this combination.

---

**Path planning**

Yes, you could give a robot a GPS and a target location and have it plan a route and move to the new location.

Sounds easy doesn't it?

It isn't.

It really, *really* isn't!

Path planning is a complicated discipline. There is an introductory course on [Computational Motion Planning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/robotics-motion-planning) available (free to audit last time I looked) on Coursera if you are interested. It's part of a Robotics "Speciality", so depending on your existing skills, you might want to work through the modules in sequence.

[If you do decide to do all the modules in the Speciality, I shared [my notes](https://www.scribd.com/lists/15471316/Aerial-Robotics-notes) for some of the modules via my Scribd account. Some of these also contain elements on motion planning. (***Be warned***, some of them also contain a lot of maths!)]

The best practical advice I can give is to start small.

I tested my robots in a local park, over distances measured in tens, rather than hundreds of metres. I then introduced obstacles (trees) in a different part of the park, and things got a whole lot more interesting! (Not least, of course, because GPS really doesn't like trees! So you have to use other sensors when the robot isn't receiving data from the GPS ...).

And if you think that's complicated, just wait until you introduce "moving obstacles", like people, dogs, cars, bicycles, ...!

---

Hopefully that will give you some pointers to get you started. When you hit problems with your code (and you're almost certainly going to hit problems with your code!), sites like this will be a godsend.

I really wish Arduino: SE had been around back when I was banging my head against the proverbial wall trying to work out why my code wasn't doing what I expected it to!

Answer (score 1):

See this site, for a practical example:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Powered-Autonomous-Vehicle/